# How can I identify objects in the resulting ArrayList of AnimatorSet.getChildAnimations()?

Tags: java, android, animation, animator, animatorset

So I've got a method (method 1) that returns an `AnimatorSet` to another method (method 2). In method 2, I'd like to pick some of the `Animator`'s inside the `AnimatorSet`, and use them independently of each other.

I found the `.getChildAnimations()` method, which should help me in some way, but unfortunately, I don't know how to work the `ArrayList<Animator>` properly. I tried using a `.toString()` on the items in the `ArrayList`, so I might be able to identify the `Animators` by title, but that returns `android.animation.RevealAnimator@.....`, so basically nothing useful.

```
ArrayList<Animator> animatorList = animatorSet.getChildAnimations();
for (Animator a : animatorList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "show: "+a.toString());
}
```

result:

```
05-08 14:02:25.177 11044-11044/com.example.tim.timapp D/CStA: show: android.animation.RevealAnimator@17e554b
05-08 14:02:25.177 11044-11044/com.example.tim.timapp D/CStA: show: android.animation.RevealAnimator@3c95b28
05-08 14:02:25.177 11044-11044/com.example.tim.timapp D/CStA: show: android.animation.RevealAnimator@f723041
```

So, how can I identify `Animators` inside an `AnimatorSet`, so I can pick those that I need?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I deleted my answer. I will give it a try and see if I can try it myself